# The Program was supposed to go on Forever

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;;)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ((i++) * i) ^ i);
    }
}
```

Compiling , it runs till the Limit and goes to negative integer.Why this behaviour?

Did it for fun while reading the For statement syntax...

Comment: Read about [for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) and [integer overflow](https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/).

Comment: The title and the question is completely unrelated - please fix

Comment: Could u suggest a suitable title...it would be wonderful of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `int` type to be of 32 bits. Since 'i' starts from zero, it will be something like this:

`00000 ..... 32 times`

After i++:

`00000000000000000000000000000001`

This will keep on incrementing until it becomes:

`0111 .. (31 1's)`

After the next increment you go into the negative number:

`10000  ...(31 0's)`

In 2's complement above is -((2^32)).

Further after many post increments it becomes:

`11111111111111111111111111111111  (32 times 1)`

Above is -1.

When the next increment occurs it becomes:

`0000 ... (all 32 zeroes)`

and this process continues.

Answer (score 1):

Your program invokes undefined behavior twice, integer overflow and unsequenced expression (`(i++)*i)^i`).

Sequence points [**ISO/IEC 9899:2017C17 N2176**](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) § B.29:

> - Between the evaluations of the function designator and actual arguments in a function call and the actual call. (6.5.2.2).
> - Between the evaluations of the first and second operands of the following operators: logical AND&&(6.5.13); logical OR||(6.5.14); comma,(6.5.17).
> - Between the evaluations of the first operand of the conditional ?: operator and whichever of the second and third operands is evaluated (6.5.15).
> - Between the evaluation of a full expression and the next full expression to be evaluated. The following are full expressions: a full declarator for a variably modified type; an initializer that is not part of a compound literal (6.7.9); the expression in an expression statement; the controlling expression of a selection statement (if or switch) (6.8.4); the controlling expression of a while or do statement (6.8.5); each of the (optional) expressions of a for statement (6.8.5.3);the (optional) expression in a return statement (6.8.6.4).
> - Immediately before a library function returns (7.1.4).
> - After the actions associated with each formatted input/output function conversion specifier(7.21.6, 7.29.2).
> - Immediately before and immediately after each call to a comparison function, and also between any call to a comparison function and any movement of the objects passed as arguments to that call (7.22.5).

Undefined Beahaviour [**ISO/IEC 9899:2017C17 N2176**](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) § 3.4.3:

> 1 - **undefined behavior** - **behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.**
>
> 2 - **Note 1 to entry**: Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with orwithout the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnosticmessage).
>
> 3 - **EXAMPLE**: **An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow**.

For GCC, the compile doesn't show none of those warnings by default, if you use `gcc file.c -Wall -Wextra` the sequence point warning is issued, Integer overflow is not part of these generic flags, I'm sure there is a specialized one, you can look in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Pardon me for asking, the only error was the Wsequence which indicated the undefined sequence but none about the integer overflow... I also declared the flag - Wstrict-overflow